# Cast to number failed for value - GraphQL

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, graphql-js, express-graphql

I'm new to graphQL. I'm trying to play with graphiql and I'm trying to perform a `where` Where I want to retrive the authors with age greater than 30.

**resolver.js**

```
Query: {

        authorGratherThan: (root, { age }) => {
            return authorModel.where({
                age: {
                    _gte: 30
                }
            });
        }

    },
```

**graphiql tool**

```
{
  authorGratherThan(age:30) {
    name,
    age,
  }
}
```

Schema model
**author.js**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import uuid from 'node-uuid';
const schema = mongoose.Schema;

const authorsSchema = new schema({
    id: { type: String, default: uuid.v1 },
    name: String,
    age: Number,
    books: [ String ]
});

const model = mongoose.model('author', authorsSchema);
export default model;
```

**Getting this error:**

> "message": "Cast to number failed for value \"{ _gte: 30 }\" at path
>   \"age\" for model \"author\"",

Comment: What is your database type?

Comment: MongoDB. I have updated my question with the schema model

Comment: Just use `.find` instead of `.where` - https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find , your code will come to `authorModel.find({age: { $gte: 30 }})`

Comment: @hoangdv feel free to post the answer so you get the points! Thanks so much

Comment: @hoangdv FYI: using where worked too but the error was that i was using _gte instead of $gte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `.find` instead of `.where` - [doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) , your code will come to

```
authorModel.find({age: { $gte: 30 }})
```

or we can instead write,

```
authorModel.where('age').gte(30)
```